# Cleaning up a varied list that contains strings and tuples with unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list that is taken from  id3. tags from an .mp3. When i print the list, its a mixture of strings and tuples with unicode.

I get the following from  a straight print out of the list.

```
[('album', [u'Singles']), ('artist', [u'Led Zeppelin']), ('title', [u'Kashmir'])]
```

I want to have this:

album  Singles, artist Led Zeppelin, title Kashmir

I have tried to use the following:

```
nvar = filter(lambda x: x!="[u'" and x!="(" and x!=")" and x!="]", var)
```

which prints:

```
[('album', [u'Singles']), ('artist', [u'Led Zeppelin']), ('title', [u'Kashmir'])]
```

I can use:

```
>>> nvar = filter(lambda x: x!="[" and x!="'" and x!="(" and x!=")" and x!="]", str(var))
>>> nvar
'album, uSingles, artist, uLed Zeppelin, title, uKashmir'
```

but I am left with the u from unicode. If I use x!="u", then any word with a u in it will wrong after that function runs.

Also this seems to be the hard way to do things.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `tags` is indeed a Python list containing 2-tuples of (str, list), then:

```
tags = [('album', [u'Singles']), ('artist', [u'Led Zeppelin']), ('title', [u'Kashmir'])]
print ', '.join('{} {}'.format(el[0], el[1][0]) for el in tags)
# album Singles, artist Led Zeppelin, title Kashmir
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work. Since the 'u' is between the '(' and "'" it will not affect the 'real' data.

```
    def Plain(self, U_String) :
          P_String = str(U_String)
          m=re.search("^\(\u?\'(.*)\'\,\)$", P_String)
          if (m) :  #Typical unicode
             P_String = m.group(1).decode("utf8")
          return P_String
```